# question_ids not defined for user agent and web link

Tags: surveymonkey

I have got results back from a survey. There are two question IDs in the answers that are not defined in get_survey_details. They are obviously the user agent and web page (or maybe a collector?) but I now have to handle these undefined question IDs when processing. If I find a question_id that is not in the details, how can I tell that it is a predefined type (that can be ignored because it's not really an answer) and not invalid or corrupt data that needs to be raised as an error? Is it perhaps the presence of `"row": "0"` ?

```
{"answers": [{"text": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; ...etc...", "row": "0"}], "question_id": "592799546"}, 
{"answers": [{"text": "http://www.example.com/someurlorother", "row": "0"}], "question_id": "592799547"},
```

Comment: Are these custom variables on the survey?  If you're happy to share the survey_id or link on here I can check it out, otherwise I suggest emailing api-support@surveymonkey.com with this one.

Comment: Thanks, Miles, I don't think they could be custom variables which are strings that the user specifies, they look like browser info to me. 
I had substituted "example" for the real name, so I'll go for api-support on this one. I googled for
`"user agent" site:surveymonkey.com`
but got nothing relevant.

Comment: My app checks for referential integrity in the data.
There are question types like descriptive_text (that is Qtype 160 which is undocumented in QuestionTable.html in the RD download) which are in the survey but have no responses.
Here we have responses without question ids in the survey_details.

Comment: Just to finish this: You were right, @Miles, they are Custom Variables: User Agent and Page. I have now heard from Surveymonkey support that the API does not yet handle Custom Variables. They ARE exported in the Relational Database format, but that export format is being retired so I am writing the code to generate that from the json data. It is completed, except for those variables where in the meantime I will have to generate dummy type 90 questions.